# iOS facedetection works differently in simulator and device

Tags: ios, face-detection, core-image

I am trying to use iOS 5 facedetection, and I'm finding that when I run the code on the simulator, it detects a face with correct frame. However, if I run the exact same code on the same image on the device, it returns incorrect dimensions.
Here's my code:

```
CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:someImage.CGImage];

NSDictionary *detectorOptions =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorAccuracy,
 nil];

CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                          context:nil
                                          options:detectorOptions];


NSArray *faceFeatures = [detector featuresInImage:image];
for (CIFeature *f in faceFeatures) {
  NSLog(@"Feature: %@", NSStringFromRect(f.bounds));
}
```

The output from the simulator (correct):
Feature: `{{78, 153}, {200, 200}}`

The output from the device (incorrect):
Feature: `{{104, 199}, {272, 272}}`

Is this a bug? Or am I improperly using the face detection code? I've also tried using featuresInImage:options and passing in another dictionary with the device orientation

Comment: Where did `someImage` come from on the simulator?  Where did it come from on the device?

Comment: someImage is an image from the ALAssetLibrary, namely asset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: What happens if you use `fullResolutionImage` instead of `fullScreenImage`?

Comment: Resolution: 360x480 ... Let me look into switching to fullResolution

Comment: Is one of the devices a retina display device and the other not? If yes, try on two devices (simulator and device) that have the same display type.

Comment: Also check the `orientation` property of the `ALAssetRepresentation` on both platforms.

Comment: Aha! That's what it is. When I switched to retina on my simulator, I see same behavior as the device...

Now the next question is: what adjustments need to be made to get this to work on retina.

Comment: The other thing to remember: it's a _simulator_ not an _emulator_. There is no guarantee that the benahiour is identical to real hardware. You'll also find that face detection is a lot quicker on your Mac...